# Replace <strong> tags with <br /> tags using .getElementByClassName

Tags: javascript, html

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acdpy0co/3/)

I have the following HTML that is created by my billing software. The issue is that I need line breaks after each `</strong>` tag so that the text isnt all on one line. I can't add spacing between `<p>` tags in the CSS because its generated as one long string.

I only have access to the Javascript

```
<div class="highlightbox">
    <h2>VPNt</h2>
    <p>As Low as<strong> $8.33/month</strong>
    <strong>Best Plan for Heavy Users</strong>
    Random IP Address-------------------<strong>YES!</strong>
    Ever Changing IP Address-----------<strong>YES!</strong>
    US IP Address--------------------------<strong>YES!</strong>
    Logging the Sites you Visit.--------<strong>NEVER!</strong>
    Super Secure Privacy-----------------<strong>YES!</strong>
    Great for P2P---------------------------<strong>YES!</strong>
    Super High Speed---------------------<strong>YES!</strong>
    Great for Streaming-------------------<strong>YES!</strong>
    US Video Services --------------------<strong>YES!</strong>
    Runs on Windows -------------------<strong>YES!</strong>
    Runs on Mac---------------------------<strong>YES!</strong>
    Runs on IOS --------------------------<strong>YES!</strong>
    No Overage Charges-----------------<strong>YES!</strong>
    Host Servers-----------------------------<strong>No</strong>
    <em>Use our Static IP service for hosting servers</em><br/>
    <strong>Unlimited Bandwidth-------------------YES!</strong>
    </p></div>
```

I first tried this

```
pholder = document.getElementByClassName('highlightbox');
pholder.innerHTML = pholder.innerHTML.replace(/(\<\/strong\>)/g, "$1\<br\>");
```

But I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var pholderStrongs = document.querySelectorAll('.highlightbox p strong');

for (var i = 0; i < pholderStrongs.length; ++i)
{
    pholderStrongs[i].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<br />');
}
```

See [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

Comment: Good answer, except don't use `for-in` on DOM collections. It can cause bugs. Use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using CSS:

```css
.highlightbox>p {
    white-space:pre; /* or pre-wrap, if preferred */
}
```

```css
.highlightbox>p {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="highlightbox">
    <h2>VPNt</h2>
    <p>As Low as<strong> $8.33/month</strong>
    <strong>Best Plan for Heavy Users</strong>
    Random IP Address-------------------<strong>YES!</strong>
    Ever Changing IP Address-----------<strong>YES!</strong>
    US IP Address--------------------------<strong>YES!</strong>
    Logging the Sites you Visit.--------<strong>NEVER!</strong>
    Super Secure Privacy-----------------<strong>YES!</strong>
    Great for P2P---------------------------<strong>YES!</strong>
    Super High Speed---------------------<strong>YES!</strong>
    Great for Streaming-------------------<strong>YES!</strong>
    US Video Services --------------------<strong>YES!</strong>
    Runs on Windows -------------------<strong>YES!</strong>
    Runs on Mac---------------------------<strong>YES!</strong>
    Runs on IOS --------------------------<strong>YES!</strong>
    No Overage Charges-----------------<strong>YES!</strong>
    Host Servers-----------------------------<strong>No</strong>
    <em>Use our Static IP service for hosting servers</em><br/>
    <strong>Unlimited Bandwidth-------------------YES!</strong>
    </p></div>
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to vote for this, except that the OP doesn't seem to control the HTML generation, so it could be risky.

Comment: @sixfingeredman More risky than using JavaScript to hack around with the HTML? Worst that can happen with my CSS is that it causes something else to look weird, in which case all you have to do is make the selector more specific.

Comment: This is a good solution that i didnt think of. Will upvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with JQuery `.append()`:

```
$('strong').append('<br />');
```

I don't think .innerHTML can return every element that's inside it. It's text only.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mvoc814f/)

Comment: "`innerHTML` is text only"... right... makes sense to call it `innerHTML` then, doesn't it?